# Iterate over a list of dictionaries in python without repeats?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am looking for guidance on how to iterate over a list of dictionaries, renaming some key/value pairs and removing others. I have code that performs the necessary transformations, but it creates many duplicates of the new dictionaries.

Here is the background:

I have a list of dictionaries called "results". There are 3 dictionaries in the list. Each dictionary in results contains 5 key/value pairs like this...

```
{'lat': 36.88773, 
 'site_description': blah blah, 
 'id': 2, 
 'long': -75.985534, 
 'site_name': 62nd street}
```

I am trying to create a new dictionary out of each one in the list. I want to perform the following changes:

- Rename 'long' to 'lng'
- Rename 'site_description' to 'infobox'
- Drop 'id'

The code that I have below will successfully iterate over the list of dictionaries and transform each one. However, instead of just creating 3 new dictionaries, I am creating 15. There are 5 duplicates of each new dictionary.

```
>>> black_list = {"id"}
>>> rename ={"long":"lng", "site_description":"infobox"}
>>> new_markers = []
>>> for dict in results:
       for val in dict.items():
           new_markers.append({rename.get(key, key) : val for key, val 
               in dict.items() if key not in black_list})
>>> print new_markers
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for dict in results:
   for val in dict.items():
       new_markers.append({ … dict comprehension … })
```

You have two loops there, and the second iterates over the dictionary items although you alrady do that in the dictionary comprehension later. Especially since you are also retrieving `val` from looping over `dict.items()` there.

So just skip that one loop and you should be good to go.

```
for dict in results:
   new_markers.append({rename.get(key, key) : val for key, val 
           in dict.items() if key not in black_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

Comprehension of list and dict is one way to do it:

```
new_markers = [{rename[k] if k in rename else k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in black_list} for d in results]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = [{'lat': 36.88773, 'site_description': "blah blah", 'id': 2, 'long': -75.985534, 'site_name': "62nd street"}, {'lat': 36.88773, 'site_description': "blah blah", 'id': 4, 'long': -35.985534, 'site_name': "26nd street"}, {'lat': 36.88773, 'site_description': "blah blah", 'id': 2, 'long': -75.985534, 'site_name': "62nd street"}]

new_s = [{"lng" if a == "log" else 'infobox' if a == 'site_description' else a if a != "id" else "pass":b for a, b in i.items()} for i in s]
final_list = []
for i in new_s:
   del i["pass"]
   final_list.append(i)
```

Output:

```
[{'long': -75.985534, 'infobox': 'blah blah', 'site_name': '62nd street', 'lat': 36.88773}, {'long': -35.985534, 'infobox': 'blah blah', 'site_name': '26nd street', 'lat': 36.88773}, {'long': -75.985534, 'infobox': 'blah blah', 'site_name': '62nd street', 'lat': 36.88773}]
```

Comment: Thanks I will test this out, too.